# Why gradle cannot get version by platform

Tags: java, gradle

For project `lib`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(platform(project(":dependencies")))

  api("a.b.c:third")
}
```

For project `app`

```
dependencies {
  //implementation(platform(project(":dependencies")))

  api(project(":lib"))
}
```

If I remove `implementation(platform(project(":dependencies")))` on `app`, gradle shows me:

```
Could not find a.b.c:third:.
Required by:
    project :app > project :lib
```

I'm confused: project `lib` has been imported `platform(project(":dependencies"))`, it should known version of `a.b.c:third`, why `app` didn't known the version?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but in the `lib` project, you probably need to use `api` instead of `implementation` for the platform in order for it to contribute the version to the other `api` dependency.

Comment: @BjørnVester you are right. But api means expose `project(":dependencies")`, I don't want to expose it so I use `implementation`